# Having trouble with objects in lists for SIMPLE adventure game

Tags: c#, list, class, object

I have to do a simple adventure game for my C# programming class. I decided to do this but I think I may be a little bit ahead of myself.

I figured out how to make a list for the rooms and items. I have a class for `Item` and `Room`.  Inside each class is a variable for `String Name, String Desc, and int ItemNum` along with gets and sets for each.  Then in the `World` class I have two lists. `public static List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();` and `public static List<Item> items = new List<Item>();`

To add something to the lists I use

`rooms.Add(new Room {Name = "Prison", Desc = "This is text", ItemNum = 1});`
`items.Add(new Item {Name = "Key", Desc = "This is a key", ItemNum = 1 });`

My issue is I don't know how to "get" something. Like if user types in Name and wanted Desc how do I do that?
I tried this but couldn't get it to work.

```
var match =
    from t in rooms
    where t.Name == "temp"
    select t.Desc;

foreach (var element in match) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

The other thing is moving rooms. Would the easiest way be to add another variable to `Item` and `Room` called `CurrentRoom = 0` and change it to 1 if the room was current. So if you wanted to know your current room there was be something to look for whatever room have `CurrentRoom = 1`??

Any help is appreciated.  Only thing I asked it if there is a better way to do something remember I am still a beginning and have not done much past LINQ and inheritance

Thanks for any help!
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ statement for finding the item descriptions based upon a name look largely correct. The main thing to bear in mind when doing string comparisons/searching is case-sensitivity, if they type "prison" should it return the description of the room named "Prison"?

To achieve a case-insensitive lookup, you can do the following:

```
var descriptions = from r in rooms
                   where r.Name.Equals("prison", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                   select r.Desc;
foreach(var description in descriptions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(description);
}
```

As stated by gpmurthy, if this is a frequent operation, use a form of a Dictionary, I would personally use implementations of the [`KeyedCollection(TKey,TItem)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

The concept of a current room is going to be largely dependent upon the structure of the rest of your implementation. If you have a `Player` class, add a `CurrentRoom` property to that, e.g.

```
public class Player
{
    public Room CurrentRoom { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Cool, that should help I'll give that a shot

Comment: @user3064291 Did you find my answer of any use? If so, be sure to leave an upvote or accept as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a sound solution. If you are going to be doing frequent lookups I would recommend changing the List to a Dictionary....

```
Dictionary<string, Room>
Dictionary<string, Item>
```

This would significantly improve performance for multiple lookups.

Good Luck!

Comment: Okay, but how does that differ from lists and I wouldstill need to know how to look things up like I asked

Comment: Searching inside the object in a list would require checking all the objects in the List. Whereas in a dictionary the lookup happens very fast (close to O(1)). The following link hopefully should help... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx